# Magento - How to Edit container1

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am looking to edit the container1 and container2 product information in my magento template. In view mytemplate/template/catalog/view.phtml and I see these container1 and container2 calls.

After some research, I should be looking for an options directory, but that does not exist in my template.

Is this something I am suppose to add if its not there? Hopefully someone can help as I am definitely hoping to add a new div class and some new options to this Add to Cart/product-options area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to actually add options, you would do that through the admin interface. If you're trying to change aspects of the template affecting how options are displayed, you would indeed be looking for options .phtml files. Specifically, in your theme path, something like:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/options
```

And there will be two files:

```
wrapper.phtml
wrapper/bottom.phtml
```

In the future you might also want to look into enabling theme hints through your admin interface:

```
System > Configuration

Change current configuration scope to anything more specific than "Default Config".

Advanced > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints > Yes
```

After enabling this mode, open the product view page and each element on the page will also show which .phtml it is being generated by. If this is a live site, you might also want to set your IP address under the Developer Client Restriction Allowed IP so nobody else sees the hints.

Comment: Thank you for the Template Path Hints, that will come in handy in the future.  Here it just continues to cause confusion.  What I knew I was looking for, which you confirmed was in /view/options, is not in my theme, only in the base/default which I obviously do not want to touch.  Do I just copy this direct and file to my template?

Comment: Try using the theme hints.. although it may just confirm that you are indeed using the default template for those elements which as you correctly suspected,  in most cases do not want to edit but rather have a copy in your theme directory and edit that. There is a good explanation of the theming hierarchy and fall-back structure here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy